# ffmpeg multiple filters not working

Tags: ffmpeg, command-line

I am trying to specify multiple filters for ffmpeg and I am getting an error output.

I am trying to do an audio and video fade in and a resolution scale.

my command is as follows...

```
ffmpeg -i 00021.MTS -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 -vf fade=in:0:500, afade=in:0:300, scale=384:218, scaled.avi
```

and the error it gives me is as follows.....

> [NULL @ 0xb72ce0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'afade=in:0:300,'
>   afade=in:0:300,: Invalid argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audio and video filters are invoked in separate chains. And without enclosing quotes, whitespace will break the chain.

```
ffmpeg -i 00021.MTS -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 -vf "fade=in:0:500, scale=384:218" -af afade=in:0:300 scaled.avi
```